# I can jump by drag gesture in PreView but fail in Simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to jump from ContentView to ViewDrag and jump between View123 by draging. But now, From ViewDrag's PreView, I can drag and jump successfully. But if I jump from ContentView to ViewDrag firstly, I can't use gesture in ViewDrag anymore!
My minimal code is followed:

```
    @State var Jump = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
        VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    Jump = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("JUMP")
                })
            }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $Jump, destination: {
            ViewDrag()
        })
        }
    }
}

struct ViewDrag: View {
    @State private var currentPage = 0
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            if currentPage == 0 {
                View1(nextPage: $currentPage)
                    .transition(.customTransition)
            } else if currentPage == 1 {
                View2(nextPage: $currentPage)
                    .transition(.customTransition)
            } else if currentPage == 2 {
                View3(nextPage: $currentPage)
                    .transition(.customTransition)
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .updating($translation, body: { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.width
                })
                .onEnded({ value in
                    if value.translation.width < 0 && currentPage < 4 {
                        withAnimation {
                            currentPage += 1
                        }
                    } else if value.translation.width > 0 && currentPage > 0 && currentPage != 4 {
                        withAnimation {
                            currentPage -= 1
                        }
                    }
                })
        )
    }
}
    extension AnyTransition {
        static var customTransition: AnyTransition {
            let transition = AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading)
                .combined(with: .opacity)
            
            return .asymmetric(insertion: transition, removal: transition)
        }
    }
struct View1: View {
    @Binding var nextPage: Int
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am View1")
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Binding var nextPage: Int
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am View2")
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    @Binding var nextPage: Int
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("I am View3")
    }
}
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated!

Comment: As a start, try to make a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This doesn't only help in creating a better question, but is also an excellent way of debugging issues.

Comment: Thank Jack Goossen's advice! I have restarted a project and minimal my code.And I have put my minimal code in my question, looking forward to your help!

Comment: What is the purpose of the nextPage `Binding` and translation `GestureState` in View1-3? They do not seem to be used at all.

Comment: I am sorry, I am a new Swift developer(may be not even a developer). I think you are right, they are not useful. I will delete them.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I just posted another question. If you have time, could you please help me take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your ViewDrag view. You attach the gesture to a NavigationStack, but that view itself is transparent and does not capture touches. If you manage to drag the Text in the sub views itself, you'll see that your example actually works!

Now I don't think the nested NavigationControllers is necessary or a good idea. But you'll probably want a container view that captures the touches. You can do this as follows using a ZStack, Color.clear and specifying a contentShape:

```
struct ViewDrag: View {
    @State private var currentPage = 0
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // make the ZStack fill the available space
            Color.clear 

            if currentPage == 0 {
                View1(nextPage: $currentPage)
                    .transition(.customTransition)
            } else if currentPage == 1 {
                View2(nextPage: $currentPage)
                    .transition(.customTransition)
            } else if currentPage == 2 {
                View3(nextPage: $currentPage)
                    .transition(.customTransition)
            }
        }
        // make sure the ZStack captures touches in the full
        // rectangle it occupies (even when transparent)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .gesture(
        ...
```